# compilation error in Integrating apple video kit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have integrating Apple purchased videokit in a separate project and it was working fine, but when I am integrating in am old project which already have lot of stuff then it is throwing an error while compiling.
The error is: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoBZR.png)

```
import "VKPlayerViewController.h"
import "VKDecodeManager.h"
import "VKPlayerController.h"
```

While importing these headers in my bridging header file it is giving the following error:

```
Failed to import bridging header '/Users/iOS2/.../SVN/../my-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I have also integrated 3rd party sdk `Linphone` before integrating ios videokit in my project. The problem could be due to multiple header paths for both the sdks which i'm not able to find out. 
Please help!

Comment: Forgotten to `#include <avcodec.h>` at the top of that header file?

Comment: I have referred  this link http://iosvideokit.com/2015/06/06/using-ios-videokit-as-an-objective-c-static-library-in-a-swift-project/ for integration and after adding avcodec.h in header file it is throwing more errors.

Comment: "more errors" is not enough information.